# Make a newtype instance of Eq

Tags: haskell, typeclass, hugs, deriving

I'm learning Haskell and I've been given following assignment - I have a newtype consisting of two mixed data types, and I have to make it an instance of Eq without using deriving. Here's what I have:

```
data Number = One | Two | Three deriving Eq
data Character = A | B | C deriving Eq
newtype Combo = Combo ((Character, Character),(Number, Number))

instance Eq Combo where
    Combo ((a1, a2),(x1,x2)) == Combo ((b1, b2),(y1, y2)) = (a1 == b1) && (a2 == b2) && (x1 == y1) && (x2 == y2)
```

However, Hugs goes all

```
ERROR "testing.hs":5 - Ambiguous class occurrence "Eq"
*** Could refer to: Hugs.Prelude.Eq Main.Eq Main.Eq Main.Eq Main.Eq Main.Eq
```

How do I fix this? I can't really import Eq hiding something either since I need it to check if a given member of Number or Character is equal.

Comment: If that's really all code you have, then it might be a bug in Hugs. Also, please note that Hugs is no longer in development.

Comment: Yeah, but I have to use it, unfortunately.

Comment: are you sure you have not redefined `class Eq` somewhere in your file (or the grader ... oh wait it's FP101x right? So it probably has no grader)

Comment: btw: there is probably an `Eq` instance for 2-tuples already so you could make this a bit shorter ... something like `Combo c == Combo c' = c == c'` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Changing

```
instance Eq Combo where
Combo ((a1, a2),(x1,x2)) == Combo ((b1, b2),(y1, y2)) = (a1 == b1) && (a2 == b2) && (x1 == y1) && (x2 == y2)
```

to

```
instance Main.Eq Combo where
Combo ((a1, a2),(x1,x2)) == Combo ((b1, b2),(y1, y2)) = (a1 == b1) && (a2 == b2) && (x1 == y1) && (x2 == y2)
```

apparently fixed that error.